# Как поменять слова местами в строках(Си)!

Tags: c, строки, символы

Вводится строка, состоящая из каких-либо слов, например:

> "My name is qwe."

Как поменять слова местами, чтобы получилось:

> "qwe is name My."

Всё, чего я смог добиться, это поменять буквы местами. Советовали находить слова, то есть проверять наличие символов до пробела, — но каким образом я должен переносить целое слово в другую строку, в правильном порядке и в нужное место? Это возможно только посимвольно. Но в таком случае, это то же самое, что делал я. Уже совсем отчаялся. Есть идеи?

*P.S.* Первый курс, так что задача должна решаться на основе простейших функций.

---

**Дополнение:**

Вы, видимо, не понимаете, программа какого уровня мне нужна, всё супер-супер просто. Всем, кто отвечал, большое спасибо, но надо ещё проще, без создания своих функций, без сложных циклов, без нетипичных функций. Единственный подходящий вариант из написанных — это перевернуть каждое слово из уже полностью перевёрнутой строки. Кто-то может подсказать, как именно ЭТО реализовать?
Код приложил:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>

#define N 50

void main()
{
    char str1[N];
    char str2[N];
    int i1 = 0, i2, l;
    printf("Vvedite stroku: ");
    gets(str1);
    strcpy(str2,str1);
    l = strlen(str1);
    i2 = l - 1;
    for(i1, i2; i1 <= l - 1; i1++, i2--)
    {
        str1[i1] = str2[i2];
    }
    printf("Ishodnaya stroka: %s\n",str2);
    printf("Preobrazovannaya: %s\n",str1);
    system("pause");
}
```

Получается так:

> ewq si eman yM

Сделал, можете закрывать, всем спасибо за помощь (нет). Правда, надо перед первым и после последнего слов пробелы ставить, чтобы работало.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<string.h>
#define N 50
void main()
{
char str1[N];
char str2[N];
char str3[N];
int i1=0,i2,l,k1=0,k2=0,k3;
printf("Vvedite stroku: ");
gets(str1);
strcpy(str2,str1);
l = strlen(str1);
i2=l-1;
for (i1,i2;i1<=l-1;i1++,i2--)   
{
 str2[i1]=str1[i2];
}
i1=0;i2=l-1;
strcpy(str3,str2);
for (i1;i1<=N;i1++)
{
 k2=i1;
 k3=i1;
 if (str2[i1]==' ')
 {  

    for (k1,k2;k1<=k3;k2--,k1++)
    {
        str3[k1]=str2[k2];
    }
    k1=k3;
    k2=k3;
   }
  }
 printf("Ishodnaya stroka: %s\n",str1);
printf("Preobrazovannaya: %s\n",str2);
printf("Preobrazovannaya: %s\n",str3);
system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Если слова имеют одинаковую длинну - проблем нету, если разную - нужно делать сдвиг символов от одного слова до другого.

Comment: Что бы меньше заморачиватся, проще создать строку с новыми символами на базе старой.

Comment: Это все понятно,мне нужен алгоритм.Я уже 2 дня думаю и копаю весь интернет,пока не нашел ни одного внятного ответа.

Comment: @StupidStudent. А вы не интернет копайте, а учебник по С. О том, как располагается строка в памяти.

Comment: И что мне это должно дать ?Я знаю что такое строка и каким образом она располагается в памяти,что дальше?Мне нужно перемещать СЛОВО, а не символ.Каким образом это сделать ?

Comment: Важный момент,задача решается общим видом, то есть должна работать для любого кол-ва слов и любого размера,не получится просто написать 100 строк кода в котором я каждый символ перемещаю туда куда мне надо.Все должно быть алгоритмизированно!

Comment: задача очень легко решается рекурсивно. Если строка содержит одно слово (то есть, нет пробелов), то это слово и есть результат. Иначе разделяем строку на голову (первое слово, до пробела) и хвост. Результат - перевернутый хвост плюс пробел плюс голова.

Comment: ИМХО, чтобы страдания студента были конструктивны, самое время попросить его выложить код сделанного, и мучить, подсказывая, где и какие нужно внести изменения, но которые он должен сделать  сам.

Comment: И все-таки (а жаль...) студент не понял красоты алгоритма с переворотом.

Comment: `system("tac -s ' ' < my_cool_file");`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сначала перевернуть побуквенно всю строку целиком, потом искать отдельные слова и обратно их переворачивать.

Comment: Буквы перевернуты,как происходит поиск отдельных слов ?Программа не знает длинны слов и правильного расположения букв в строке.Я же говорю,вся соль в том что задача общего вида,нельзя просто вручную их переворачивать.Нужен алгоритм.

Comment: Крутой вариант кстати, находишь начало и конец слова и работаешь между ними тем же алгоритмом, которым разворачивал всю строку.

Comment: @OlegBrezhnev, ага, тоже про это подумал, когда прочитал ответ.

Comment: Как его найти?Слов может быть 100 штук,тогда мне 200 переменных вводить для запоминания порядкового номера начала и конца каждого слова слова ?

Comment: вот для этого и придумали массивы!

Comment: @KoVadim, я бы без массивов сделал)

Comment: без массивов никак. Сама строка - это уже массив.

Comment: Последовательно каждое слово разворачивать, одно за другим. Две переменные нужны будут.

Answer (score 6):

Как я понимаю, вам нужно написать программу, используя обычные циклы. Ниже представлена демонстрационная программа, показывающая, как это можно сделать. Разделителями слов в программе считаются символ пробела `(' ')` и символ табуляции (`'\t'`)

Программа сначала подсчитывает число символов, расположенных до точки, завершающей предложение, так как точка должна оставаться на своем исходном месте.

Затем все предложение, исключая точку, реверсируется.

Затем в цикле ищутся начала и концы слов, которые в свою очередь реверсируются. Реверсию всего предложения и отдельных слов делает функция `reverse`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t find( const char *s, char c )
{
    size_t i = 0;

    while ( s[i] && s[i] != c ) i++;

    return i;
}   

char * reverse( char *s, size_t n )
{
    for ( size_t i = 0; i < n / 2; i++ )
    {
        char c = s[i];
        s[i] = s[n-i-1];
        s[n-i-1] = c;
    }

    return s;
}

int main(void) 
{
    char s[] = "My name is qwe.";

    size_t n = find( s, '.' );

    puts( s );

    reverse( s, n );

    for ( size_t i = 0; i != n; )
    {
        while ( s[i] == ' ' || s[i] == '\t' ) i++;
        if ( i != n )
        {
            size_t j = i;

            while ( ++i != n && s[i] != ' ' && s[i] != '\t' );

            reverse( s + j, i - j );
        }
    }

    puts( s );

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль

```
My name is qwe.
qwe is name My.
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот набросок кода с рекурсией. Работать будет, утечек явных нет (там может быть realloc, но это обычно выходит за пределы школьного курса). Проверялось в gcc. Самая первая строка нужна исключительно для него, что бы компилятор не ругался. Кстати, исходная строка модифицируется, но это издержки алгоритма. Можно и без этого сделать:)

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE 1
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * rev(char * str)
{
    char * pos = strchr(str, ' ');
    if (pos == NULL) {
        return strdup(str);
    } else {
        char * r = rev(pos+1);
        *pos = '\0';
        r = realloc(r, strlen(r) + 1 + strlen(str) + 1);
        r = strcat(r, " ");
        return strcat(r, str);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char * x = strdup("My name is qwe");
    char * y  = rev(x);
    if (y) {
        printf("%s\n", y);
    }
    free(x); free(y);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо конечно, но тут ситуация как с кодом на C# - это все не подойдет ,программа должна работать на простейших функциях .

Comment: так функции самые простые. проще некуда. Либо огласите список "простых" функций.

Comment: Нет, я правда не могу понять.Этот код уже другой уровень программирования,это видно невооруженным глазом,никак не уровень одного семестра.Такое точно не примут.Использование функций в функции,realloc(),free().Что это все ?Он у меня даже в компиляторе не запускается.

Comment: realloc, malloc, free - это выделение-освобождение памяти. Это очень базовые вещи для программиста на си.

Comment: Для программиста конечно,но не для уровня 1-го семестра.Это просто не нужно там.

Comment: тогда это плохой институт/препод.

Comment: Программа везде одна,на первом курсе проходятся базовые вещи:синтаксис,ввод,вывод,циклы,ветвления,строки и т.д.realloc, malloc, free просто не нужны для этого.Или они заменимы

Comment: они заменимы, если использовать не си.

Answer (score 0):

Можно например выделить каждое слово в отдельную строку, т. е. сделать массив строк. Затем вывести их в нужном порядке. Копировать слова можно с помощью strncpy. Искать слова от пробела или начала строки до пробела или конца строки.  Т. е. будет два индекса - который указывает на начало слова, и который указывает на следующий за словом символ.

Comment: Каждая строка объявляется,мы не знаем сколько пользователь введет слов 3,5,125.Подогнать решение под конкретное условие можно,но надо чтобы программа решалась при любом условии.

Comment: Динамически выделяй память, функции malloc и free

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/Yz5KwH

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int group(char ch)
{
    return isalpha(ch) ? 0 : isspace(ch) ? 1 : 2;
}

void word(char **r, char *s, int g)
{
    for (; *s && group(*s) == g; ++s)
        *((*r)++) = *s;
}

int main(void)
{
    char str[256], res[256], *s, *r;
    int next;

    while (gets(str))
    {
        r = res;

        for (next=group(s=str+strlen(str)-1); ; --s)
            if (s == str)
            {
                word(&r, s, group(*s));
                break;
            }
            else if (group(*s) != next)
            {
                word(&r, s+1, next);
                next = group(*s);
            }

        *r = 0;

        puts(res);
    }

    return 0;
}
```