# Как перевернуть массив символов?

Tags: c++

Как могу с функцией перевернуть массив символов .У меня есть массив символов-"abe gd fcd", и должен получать массив-"fcd gd abe".

Comment: А что должно быть с разделителями между словами? Или они всегда по 1 пробелу?

Comment: Всегда по 1 пробелу

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-words-in-a-given-string/

Comment: Спосибо большое.Не можно решать эту задачу только с библиотеками <iostream> И <string.h>?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/616319/281034

Comment: @TigerTV.ru, да ответ найденный вами на ruSO достойный, решение не требует дополнительной памяти (всем рекомендую зайти и плюсануть). На всякий случай приведу тут описание идеи. Сначала реверсируем всю строку. В результате слова будут переставлены как требуется, но символы в них тоже перевернуты. Теперь при втором проходе ищем начало и конец слова и реверсируем его. Повторяем для всех слов. Все.

Comment: Я заметил, что ответ есть в комментариях, поэтому не стал править свой ответ и удалил.